# angularjs variable on ui not refreshing

Tags: angularjs

my html looks as

```
 <div class="row" align="center" ng-if="searchCtrl.valid">
    <div class="col-lg-12"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Authorize to Instagram</button><br/></div>
   </div>
```

the js is

```
app.controller('AdminController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        this.valid = true;

        //see if ig login exists once login is performed using google
        gapi.client.instagramApi.validateIgLogin().execute(function(resp) {
             if(resp && resp.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                 // error
                 alert(resp.error.message);
              }else{
                  //successful response
                  console.log(resp);
                  this.valid = resp.valid;
              }
             });
        }
```

my service is coded to return false always. and i am expecting this to refresh ui and hide the button. its not working thoguh

Comment: I'm not seeing any `$scope` update/assignments in your example

Comment: $scope.$apply(); ? after last stmt in resp ? i added that but no luck

Comment: be careful using this inside callback functions. You can never be sure that it's going to be what you expect. Why not move `this.valid` to `$scope.valid`. You'll probably have to update your binding to `ng-if="valid"` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having two problems.

This first one is that `this` in your `gapi` callback doesn't refers to the controller anymore, so you may want to keep a reference to your controller.

The second one is that this `gapi` call is asynchronous and not part of the Angular api, so Angular will not be aware of any change that is made within its callback until the next digest cycle. In order to force a digest cycle, so can use `$scope.$apply`.

Here is a solution with both fixes:

```
app.controller('AdminController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var thisController = this;

  this.valid = true;

  //see if ig login exists once login is performed using google
  gapi.client.instagramApi.validateIgLogin().execute(function(resp) {
    if(resp && resp.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
      // error
      alert(resp.error.message);
    } else {
      //successful response
      console.log(resp);
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        thisController.valid = resp.valid;
      });

    }
  });
}
```

Note that if you accept ES6 syntax, you can keep reference to the original `this` by using arrow functions:

```
app.controller('AdminController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  this.valid = true;

  //see if ig login exists once login is performed using google
  gapi.client.instagramApi.validateIgLogin().execute((resp) => {
    if(resp && resp.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
      // error
      alert(resp.error.message);
    } else {
      //successful response
      console.log(resp);
      $scope.$apply(() => {
        this.valid = resp.valid;
      });

    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the $appy service to bind data through the instergram

```
app.controller('AdminController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        this.valid = true;

        //see if ig login exists once login is performed using google
        gapi.client.instagramApi.validateIgLogin().execute(function(resp) {
             if(resp && resp.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                 // error
                 alert(resp.error.message);
              }else{
                  //successful response
                  console.log(resp);
                 $scope.$apply(function(){ this.valid = resp.valid; })

              }
             });
        }
```

Comment: care to explain why ?

Comment: because, If you use external API (jQuery, pure javacript ..etc) whatever. it's not the angular component. Angular framework is different. if you bind data to angular object from non angular object you have to inform that to angular. $apply , $digest are the methods provide by the angular to do that... otherwise angular not recognize changes